# A rollable automatic D&D 3.5 Treasure Table?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, treasure, online-resources

I am in search of a page or online tool that lets me roll the standard 3.5 treasure table.
By "roll" I mean that I don't want a "random treasure generator". I want to enter the numbers my players roll on their dice into the tool and see the results.

Does anyone know if this exist?

Answer (score 4):

This exists... but you're going to be disappointed by the answer. It's the tables in the book.

There's no automatic tool like this, because how you want to use it can't *be* automatic. There is no way to "just" put in the dice rolls, and get the results, because there are many tables linked together, each requiring different rolls be made. At best, there could be a tool that let you input the numbers from a manual roll on just the first table (the "what category of magic item" table), but why would anyone ever create a tool that automated every roll *except* the first one?

The tables are easy to use. If you don't like or can't use any of the existing automatic item generators, just use the tables manually. They're fast enough that it takes a fraction of the time it takes to look online for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: yes, of course I always use the tables... I think though, that what I am looking for, should be somewhere. If not, I will have to code it!

Comment: @Kelhendros In which case, [this cautionary tale is relevant](http://xkcd.com/1319/). :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I know this all too well. Kelhendros I recommend a program called Tablesmith; there is a huge community behind the creation of tables for the program.

Comment: @Vethor You could make that an answer!

Comment: @Vethor, if you want to give it a try, [here it is!](http://treasuretable.blogspot.com.ar/).
It only goes up to level 10, I'll be adding magic items and weapons later. Any feedback will be welcome!